# Custom ExpressionTree ToString

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I am trying to create an ExpressionVisitor in order to recreate the expression as the inputed string (with some exception such that capture variable should be displayed as text).

I am stuck when I need to visit expression member of expression member. How can I make the following :

```
public class Starter
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new SomeClass();
        test.EchoTest();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public string StringMember { get; set; }
    public SomeClass Other { get; set; }

    public void EchoTest()
    {
        var capturedString = "localStringValue";

        Echo((() => "hardcodedString"));//Ok : () => "hardcodedString"
        Echo((() => capturedString));//Ok : () => "localStringValue" (I want the value in this case)
        Echo((() => this.StringMember));//Ok : () => this.StringMember
        Echo((() => this.Other.StringMember));//Failed, expected :() => this.Other.StringMember , received : () => this.Other.this.Other
    }

    private void Echo(Expression<Func<string>> expression)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(PathVisitor.GetPath(expression));
    }
}

public class PathVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private string _path;

    protected override Expression VisitLambda<T>(Expression<T> node)
    {
        Visit(node.Body);
        _path = string.Format("() => {0}", _path);
        return node;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression node)
    {
        _path = string.Format("\"{0}\"", node.Value);
        return node;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        var generatedClass = null != Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(node.Expression.Type, typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute));
        if (node.Expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant && generatedClass)
        {
            var getter = Expression.Lambda(node); //let's eval captured Variable
            _path = string.Format("\"{0}\"", getter.Compile().DynamicInvoke());
        }
        else if (node.Expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant)
        {
            _path = string.Format("this.{0}", node.Member.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            base.Visit(node.Expression);
            var callerPath = _path;
            _path = string.Format("{0}.{1}", callerPath, _path);
        }

        return node;
    }

    public static string GetPath(Expression expression)
    {
        var visitor = new PathVisitor();
        visitor.Visit(expression);
        return visitor._path;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
ExpressionVisitor.VisitMember
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behviour since you concatenate _path wich is `this.Other` with itself:

```
var callerPath = _path;
_path = string.Format("{0}.{1}", callerPath, _path);
```

you should change it to

```
_path = string.Format("{0}.{1}", _path, node.Member.Name);
```

i.e. find prefix by applying your visitor to the `node.Expression` then add member name.